# Hooking IAT address is incorrect

Tags: c, hook, portable-executable

I'm trying to locate the entry for wglGetProcAddress (OpenGl32.dll) imported in a test application. For some reason, the import whose name is "wglGetProcAddress" does point to the same function returned by calling GetModuleHandle and GetProcAddress on Opengl32.dll.

The executable file has been loaded into memory and is a process with its thread currently suspended. The following code correctly reads the names modules and their functions imported by that executable. Hence, the IAT should not contain RVAs since it has been loaded.

```
HMODULE h = GetModuleHandle("OPENGL32.dll");
DWORD expect_addr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(h, "wglGetProcAddress");

PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR import_desc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(pmem + import_dir);
while (import_desc->Name)
{
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA thunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(pmem + import_desc->OriginalFirstThunk);
    while (thunk->u1.Function)
    {
        PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME import = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)(pmem + thunk->u1.AddressOfData);

        printf("%s 0x%X\n", import->Name, thunk->u1.Function);
        if ((DWORD)expect_addr == (DWORD)thunk->u1.Function)
        {
            printf("Found wglGetProcAddress\n");
        }
        else if (!strcmp((const char*)import->Name, "wglGetProcAddress"))
        {
            printf("Found wglGetProcAddress's import, but the function has a different value.\n");
        }
        ++thunk;
    }

    ++import_desc;
}
```

GetProcAddress from that original value returns the address 60XXC245 where XX varies, but thunk->u1.Function always returns 0xA46D8. Everything in thunk->u1 (Function, AddressOfData, Ordinal and ForwarderString) has
 the same value. The names of the import descriptors and imports correct. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Edit:
I'm trying something else: I'm scanning pmem (image of the executable in memory) for what I expect is the IAT entry, but it doesn't locate that either:

```
HMODULE h = GetModuleHandle("OPENGL32.dll");
DWORD expect_addr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(h, "wglGetProcAddress");

printf("Looking for 0x%X\n", expect_addr);
for (int i = 0; i < pmem_size - sizeof(DWORD); i++)
{
    if (*(DWORD*)(pmem + i) == expect_addr)
    {
        printf("0x%X at 0x%X\n", *(DWORD*)(pmem + i), i);
    }
}
```

**SOLVED:** I didn't realize it, but calling CreateProcess with CREATE_SUSPENDED prevents the windows loader from populating FirstThunk with the actual addresses. If I let the process run for a second and then suspend the thread, it hooks the IAT address perfectly fine. Now I have to go look for a way to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u1.Function` represents the relative offset to the `IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME` entry (or the ordinal entry if the `IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG` bit is set). this is why it doesn't match the value from `GetProcAddress`, because it isn't the address of the function, its the address of the function *import entry*.

When you have found the thunk matching your function, you need to use this too lookup the virtualized address altered by the linker, form the *other* thunk list. altering your code so it does this yeilds:

```
while (import_desc->Name)
{
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA thunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL) + import_desc->OriginalFirstThunk);
    int i = 0;
    while (thunk->u1.Function)
    {
        PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME import = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL) + thunk->u1.AddressOfData);

        void** p = (void**)((DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL) + import_desc->FirstThunk);
        printf("%s 0x%X\n", import->Name, p[i]);//thunk->u1.Function);
        if ((DWORD)expect_addr == (DWORD)p[i])
        {
            printf("Found wglGetProcAddress\n");
        }
        else if (!strcmp((const char*)import->Name, "wglGetProcAddress"))
        {
            printf("Found wglGetProcAddress's import, but the function has a different value.\n");
        }
        ++thunk;
    }

    ++import_desc;
}
```

---

To get the IAT entries, I do things a little differently:

```
inline const void** GetImportAddress(HMODULE hModule, IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR* pTable, size_t nThunk)
{
    const void** pAddressBlock = (const void**)((DWORD)hModule + pTable->FirstThunk);
    return &pAddressBlock[nThunk];      
}

const void** GetImport(HMODULE hModule, const char* szDll, const char* szFunction)
{
    const char* szDllName = NULL;
    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR* pTable = GetImportDescriptor(hModule);
    while(pTable->Characteristics != 0 && (szDllName = GetImportTableName(hModule,pTable)) != NULL)
    {
        if(!lstrcmpiA(szDll,szDllName))
        {
            IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* pThunkData = GetThunk(hModule,pTable);
            if(pThunkData != NULL)
            {
                size_t nThunk = 0;
                while(pThunkData->u1.AddressOfData != 0)
                {
                    if(pThunkData->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG)
                    {
                        if(IMAGE_ORDINAL32(pThunkData->u1.Ordinal) == (DWORD)szFunction)
                            return GetImportAddress(hModule,pTable,nThunk);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME* pImport = GetImport(hModule,pThunkData);
                        if(!lstrcmpA(szFunction,(const char*)pImport->Name))
                            return GetImportAddress(hModule,pTable,nThunk);
                    }

                    nThunk++;
                    pThunkData++;
                }
            }
        }

        pTable++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It does not match the value from GetProcAddress. How would I find the address block?

Comment: @Dmi: I added the code I use in many of my projects to do IAT hooks and lookups, should give you what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but if I use const void** addr = GetImportAddress(pmem, n) where n is the chunk index, *addr gives me 0xA46D8 again.

Comment: @Dmi: a rewrote it a bit with a fixed version of your code that works (it started off with the same problem you have). you where basically printing out the IAT offsets from FirstOriginalThunk instead of the virtualized address from FirstThunk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I'm using CreateProcess to spawn another process, and I'm trying to modify the IAT addresses of that spawned process to point to my current process, so I use the base image address of that exe instead of GetModuleHandle(0). I've tried using FirstThunk instead of FirstOriginalThunk, and it still seems to be just printing out IAT offsets.

Comment: I've edited the first post with another code question, it's too big to paste in this box.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it, but calling CreateProcess with CREATE_SUSPENDED prevents the windows loader from populating FirstThunk with the actual addresses. :/